# How to reset values of hour, minute and second in Calendar.dateComponents?

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to use a Date type without hour, minute, and second, so I'm trying to reset these values using `Calendar.dateComponents` but It doesn't work well...

Even I set `0` to those value the Date data shows `17:00:00`

How could I reset those values?

```
let today = Date()
print(today) // 2020-11-06 21:50:43 +0000
        
let calender = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

var todayComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: today)
todayComponents.hour = 0
todayComponents.minute = 0
todayComponents.second = 0

let todayFormat = calender.date(from: todayComponents)
print(todayFormat!) // 2020-11-06 17:00:00 +0000
```

---

**【UPDATED】**

I finally want to make a method to calculate a progress day from the selected date to today.

So I tried to make a method like below:

```
unc getProgressDays(startDate: String) -> String {
        // set today
        let today = Date()
        print("today:\(today)")
        
        // set today in Japan
        let todayInJapan = today.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 9)
        print("todayInJapan:\(todayInJapan)")
        
        let calender = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        var resetTodayInJapan = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: todayInJapan)
        resetTodayInJapan.hour = 0
        resetTodayInJapan.minute = 0
        resetTodayInJapan.second = 0
        let todayFormat = calender.date(from: resetTodayInJapan)
        print("todayFormat:\(todayFormat!)")

        // set startDate
        print("startDate(String):\(startDate)")
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let newStartDate =  dateFormatter.date(from: startDate)
        print("newStartDate:\(newStartDate!)")
        
        let progressDays = calender.dateComponents([.day], from: newStartDate!, to: todayFormat!).day
        print("progressDays:\(progressDays!)")
        
        return String(progressDays!)

    }
```

A console shows like below:

```
today:2020-11-07 04:25:48 +0000
todayInJapan:2020-11-07 13:25:48 +0000
todayFormat:2020-11-06 17:00:00 +0000
startDate(String):2020-09-15
newStartDate:2020-09-14 17:00:00 +0000
progressDays:53
```

I am going to use this method in Japan, so I have to localize today's date(`Date()`)

What I'm complicated are:

- When I format `todayInTokyo` using `calender.dateComponents` the new
  value gets reduced 1 day.(2020-11-07 -> 2020-11-06)
- When I convert `startDate(Strig)` to `Date` type, the `startDate` get
  reduced 1 day.(2020-09-15 -> 2020-09-14)
- `startDate(Strig)` originally doesn't have information of hour,
  minute, second but when I convert this to `Date` type the new date
  has time information(17:00:00)
- Since the original `startDate(Strig)` doesn't have time information,
  I think that I should remove a time condition of `today` value using
  `calender.dateComponents` but it doesn't work in my codes...

---

Xcode:Version 12.0.1

Comment: What time zone is your Calendar in?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. You are printing GMT time not your local time. What you need is to print the date description with the current locale `todayFormat!.description(with: .current)`

Comment: Btw there is a much easier way to accomplish what you want and avoid crashing on daylight savings transition dates where midnight might not even exist. It is called Calendar method `startOfDay(for: Date)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293783-startofday

Comment: Also consider using `let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent()` to use the user's currently selected calendar. [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1413771-autoupdatingcurrent)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I updated my question to explain in more details what I want to do and need.